# AngularJS correct syntax for variable in brace inside another brace

Tags: html, angularjs, syntax

Hello I can't find the way for doing this correctly :

```
 {{point.localized ? "{{ 'CHECKED' | translate }}" :"{{ 'I_AM_HERE' | translate }}" }}
```

point.localized is a boolean and if it's true I want to display the translation for checked and if it's not the translation for I_AM_HERE how can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
{{(point.localized ? 'CHECKED' : 'I_AM_HERE') | translate }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{{point.localized ? ('CHECKED' | translate) : ('I_AM_HERE' | translate)  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or the long way around, which is still valid:

```
<div ng-if="point.localized">
  <span>{{'CHECKED' | translate"}}</span>
</div>
<div ng-if="!point.localized">
  <span>{{'I AM HERE' | translate"}}</span>
</div>
```